# React bootstrap modal overlay bug

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, react-bootstrap

I have a problem with bootstrap modal, when i click the button, modal opens but after that when I click on back button of browser, the modal disappears(and page changes, which is good) but a black overlay remains all over the page and clicks dont work. How to solve this?

```
<button
                        type="button"
                        className="my-btn"
                        data-toggle="modal"
                        data-target={`#modal${i}`}
                      >
                        Book Now
                      </button>

                      <div
                        className="modal fade"
                        id={`modal${i}`}
                        tabIndex="-1"
                        role="dialog"
                        aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
                        aria-hidden="true"
                        data-hash="#some-hash"
                      >
                        <div className="modal-dialog" role="document">
                          <div className="modal-content">
                            <div className="modal-header">
                              <h5
                                className="modal-title"
                                id="exampleModalLabel"
                              >
                                {data.teacher.name}
                              </h5>
                              <button
                                type="button"
                                className="close"
                                data-dismiss="modal"
                                aria-label="Close"
                                onClick={() => setExactTime(null)}
                              >
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                              </button>
                            </div>
                            <div className="modal-body d-md-flex justify-content-around">
                              <div>
                                <img
                                  src={data.teacher.image}
                                  className="img-fluid"
                                  alt="teacher image"
                                />
                              </div>
                              <div className="Teacher_splited_time">
                                <p>Select Teacher Available Time slot</p>
                                {splitedTime
                                  ? splitedTime.map((val, i) => (
                                      <span
                                        key={i}
                                        style={{ display: "block" }}
                                        className={
                                          exactTime === val.timeView
                                            ? "active"
                                            : ""
                                        }
                                        onClick={
                                          AvailableOrNot(
                                            data,
                                            val.start,
                                            val.end
                                          ) === "Reserved"
                                            ? ""
                                            : () => {
                                                console.log(val);
                                                setExactTime(val.timeView);
                                                setStartTime(val.start);
                                                setEndTime(val.end);
                                              }
                                        }
                                      >
                                        {/* {TeacherBookedTime(data.teacher._id,val.start,val.end)} */}
                                        {AvailableOrNot(
                                          data,
                                          val.start,
                                          val.end
                                        ) === "Reserved"
                                          ? "Reserved"
                                          : val.timeView}
                                      </span>
                                    ))
                                  : ""}
                              </div>
                            </div>
```

The Modal looks like this:
[image]

After click on back button of browser, a black overlay and clicks dont work:
[image]

Comment: Any particular reason you're not using the `Modal` and `Button` components that come with react-bootsrtap? It would look a LOT cleaner and, possibly, even fix your problem.

Comment: @codemonkey This project was created by someone else and was handed to me recently and have been assigned to fix this bug for now. I would like to look into Modal and Button component. Can you guide me some more regarding that and what i need to replace?

Comment: Check out this Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-carson-23ewc?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @codemonkey That codepen seems to be work well when I tested it in the same page. May be i need to convert current modal into bootstrap modal component. Thanks

Comment: @codemonkey so that worked but now when i am trying to map data in modal, its not dynamic, only one data displays on all modal. While outside the modal its dynamic. How to solve this issue?